# Table Relationship Report in Oracle APEX

Tags: sql, ms-access, foreign-keys, oracle-apex, primary-key

Is there a way to create a Table Relationship Report in Oracle APEX similar to what there is in MS Access? I am trying to view a visual with all of the tables (including the names of columns) with lines between all of the relationships.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you want to see an ERD. If that's so, then - as far as I can tell - Apex is not the right tool to do that.

Use e.g. Oracle **SQL Developer** whose **Data Modeler** *is* the right tool.

In a few words:

- file - Data Modeler - Import - Data dictionary
- follow the wizard (choose schema, choose tables)
- ERD will be displayed; right click on it and choose "Discover foreign keys"

---

[image]